# base64 encode GET variables in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to get php to encode after = but before &.

```
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$out = substr(strstr($actual_link, '?'), strlen('?'));
$out = urlencode(base64_encode($out));
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/workenv/img/create.php?'.$out.'');
```

^ That encodes the whole string not each one. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/data.php?title=hi&apple=true
```

Would Be:

```
http://www.example.com/data.php?title=URLENCODEANDBASE64&apple=URLENCODEANDBASE64`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://www.example.com/data.php?title=hi&apple=true";
$out = substr(strstr($actual_link, '?'), strlen('?'));
$arr = explode('&', $out);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    $arr2 = explode('=', $arr[$i]);
    $arr2[1] = urlencode(base64_encode($arr2[1]));
    $arr[$i] = implode('=', $arr2);
}
$out = implode('&', $arr);
echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with `php` built-in functions:
[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break down the elements of the initial url,
[`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to break down the query string and
[`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to rebuild the query string

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/data.php?title=hi&apple=true';

$parts = parse_url($url);

var_dump($parts);

/* will output
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(9) "/data.php"
  ["query"]=>
  string(19) "title=hi&apple=true"
}
*/

parse_str($parts["query"],$qsArray);
var_dump($qsArray);
/* will output
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(2) "hi"
  ["apple"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}
*/
foreach($qsArray as $key=>$value){
    $encodedArray[$key]=base64_encode($value);
}
var_dump($encodedArray);
/*will output
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "aGk="
  ["apple"]=>
  string(8) "dHJ1ZQ=="
}
*/
$encodedQS = http_build_query($encodedArray); 
// http_build_query will take care of the url encoding, see below
var_dump($encodedQS);
/*will output
string(31) "title=aGk%3D&apple=dHJ1ZQ%3D%3D"
*/

$parts["query"] = "?" . $encodedQS; // prepend the "?" to the query string
$parts["scheme"] .= "://"; // append the :// bit to the scheme
$encodedURL = implode('',$parts);
var_dump($encodedURL);
/*will output
string(63) "http://www.example.com/data.php?title=aGk%3D&apple=dHJ1ZQ%3D%3D"
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Alex's answer for the same reasons that I dislike Racil's answer.  There is no need to conduct string surgery with a butter knife when php offers scalpels.

I'd like to enhance Alex's answer a little bit to accommodate variable-depth `$_GET` data by incorporating a recursive encoding call.

Code: ([Demo w/ mid-process `var_export()` calls](https://3v4l.org/rqGEj))

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/data.php?key=a&array[]=b&deepArray[c][0][d][0]=x';

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $queryArray);

array_walk_recursive($queryArray, function(&$v) {$v = base64_encode($v);});

echo "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/workenv/img/create.php?" . http_build_query($queryArray);
```